# CSS - pseudo-element

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I have some troubles with CSS. I need menu element like on the picture. The problem is I can't get green rectangle with pseudo-element. If you know non-javascript solution or have some examples I will be glad to help.

[image]

HTML

```
<li class="current">
   <a href="#section-2">Lorem Ipsum/a>
</li>
```

CSS

```
.current {
    background: red;
    &.current:after {
      content: "";
      height: 2.5em;
      margin-top: -1.25em;
      position: absolute;
      background: #ddd;
      right: -1em;
      width: 2.5em;
      z-index: 1;
    }
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vCQZ6/1/

Comment: Please post the code you've got so far (and reproduce in a jsFiddle if you can).

Comment: Why can't you simply use `border-right`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example using `border-right`. For a simple effect like that green rectangle (which in fact *is* a border) this approach is preferrable to using a pseudo-element.

### HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```css
.menu {
    list-style: none;
    background: #555;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 1em 0;
}

.menu a {
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'sans-serif';
}

.menu a:hover, .menu a:focus {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    border-right: 5px solid lightgreen;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HEc4S/)

Comment: Definitely better than usinsg pseudo elements. Wonder why that was requested?